# Postgresql: Query returning incorrect data

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Suppose i have a table `empgroupinfo` and i want to fetch the employeeid who come in exact this two groupId `500 and 501` (will come dynamically) only, should not come in more or less number of group, where `empid != 102` which is in 500 groupid.

I have tried following query:

```
select empid from empgroupinfo 
where empgroupid in(500,501) and empid != 102
group by empid having count(empid) = 2
```

But this above query also returns the empId that are in other groups.

I want to fetch the `empid` for the case when employees are in exactly these two groupids (500 and 501) only and `empid != 102`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause selects rows where `empgroupid` is either 500 or 501, not `empid`s where all the `empgroupid`s form the array `[500, 501]`.

You could use an `ARRAY_AGG` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT empid 
FROM empgroupinfo 
GROUP BY empid
-- ORDER BY clause here is important, as array equality checks elements position by position, not just 'same elements as'
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT empgroupid ORDER BY empgroupid) = ARRAY[500, 501]
```

Depending on where the `[500, 501]` array comes from, you may not know whether it itself is sorted or not. In that case a "contains AND is contained by" (operators `@>` and `<@`) should work too.

---

```
#= CREATE TABLE empgroupinfo (empid int, empgroupid int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 10,765 ms

#= INSERT INTO empgroupinfo VALUES (1, 500), (1, 501), (2, 500), (2, 501), (2, 502);
INSERT 0 5
Time: 1,451 ms

#= SELECT empid 
   FROM empgroupinfo 
   GROUP BY empid
   HAVING ARRAY_AGG(empgroupid ORDER BY empgroupid) = ARRAY[500, 501];
┌───────┐
│ empid │
├───────┤
│     1 │
└───────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0,468 ms
```

Comment: @BunkerBoy: I'm afraid I don't understand your edit. If you don't want `empId = 102` simply add a `WHERE empId <> 102` to your query.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake it was not about empid!= 102 thanks now i corrected thanks , it worked for me..

Comment: tell me one thing suppose if my groupids are 400 and 345 so will i have to array my array in asc order for according to query ?

Comment: If you know the array is sorted in descending order then you could use `ORDER BY empgroupid DESC` in the `ARRAY_AGG`. But if the ordering varies it is probably easier to sort the ids before querying Postgresql.

Comment: @ Marth  does it necessary to have consecutive number of group id or not ? for this ARRAY_AGG(empgroupid ORDER BY empgroupid)

Comment: No, there can be gaps between ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select empid 
from empgroupinfo 
group by empid 
where empid <> 102
having count(*) = 2 and min(empgroupid) = 500 and max(empgroupid) = 501
```

Comment: empgroupid is dynamic

Comment: There are only two possible values for empgroupid? Are them always contiguous? Could you give more examples?

Comment: it will be randomly